# react flux flow | how to propagate changes to other stores?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have quite simple structure 1 store, 2 components (parent and child, where parent is more like a controller), actions and constants. For now I'm no making any API calls, all data come to parent component as props.

Flow is quite simple. In child component on any change is called a callback provided by parent component.

In parent component it looks like this:

```
_saveChangedFilters: function(filterObj, filterName) {
  Actions.setActiveFilters(filterObj, filterName);
}
```

Actions:

```
setActiveFilters: function(filterObj, filterName) {
  AppDispatcher.dispatch({
    action: Constants.SET_ACTIVE_FILTER,
    filterObject: filterObj,
    filterName: filterName
  });
},
```

in Store:

```
this.dispatchToken = dispatcher.register(_.bind(function(payload) {
  switch (payload.action) {
    case Constants.MANUFACTURERS_FEED:
      this.setManufacturerStructure(payload.brands, payload.models, payload.facets);
      break;

    case Constants.SET_ACTIVE_FILTER:
      this.setActiveFilters(payload.filterObject, payload.filterName);
      this.emitChange();
      break;

    default:
  }
}, this));
```

As you can see after calling store method `setActiveFilters` I call `emitChange`. For this I have a listener in main component:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
  this.store.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
},

_onChange: function() {
  var newActiveFilters = this._getStoredActiveFilters();
  Actions.changePropagate(newActiveFilters);
  this.setState(newActiveFilters);
},
```

And here is a problem. `Actions.changePropagate` throws an Error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

As I understand the error is thrown, because I dispatch new action, before the previous was finished. So I'm still during `Actions.setActiveFilters` and call new one.

So, if I have any changes in child component, I dispatch an action, for which my store listen, this works good. But how can I add functionality, where if I have any changes in my store I can dispatch an action, which would be listen in another store without using `dispatcher.waitFor`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `dispatcher.waitFor`? Looks like that will definitely be shortest and easiest way to achieve what you want (update store 2 after store 1 has updated).

Answer (score 0):

You can consume one action in multiple stores.

Just re-use your `case Constants.SET_ACTIVE_FILTER:` in each relevant store and consume the payload accordingly for that store.

As a rule for how flux operates, "actions" should literally be **"actions"** committed by the user.  Having your code automatically call the action creator is an edge case usage and somewhat of an anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't understand. What is an antipattern? The flow I described requires my store first to proceed data and combine them with data from other filters. After this can be any change event propagated to other stores. Other stores cannot listen to SET_ACTIVE_FILTER, as there goes only currently changed filter not all object with filters... Other stores need complete object with ALL filters.